# variable scoping in javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var pic = 0;
        FB.init({appId: '1355701231239404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.session.uid + "/picture";     
            alert(pic);
         } else {
            window.location = "index.php"
         }       
        });

    });
    </script>
```

The issue is that the pic inside my if statement has a different scope with the one I declared above? Why and how do I make them the same?

What I want is to use this var pic (the one that has been assigned by the if statement) inside the body of my html. I will have another script inside the body, a document.write that uses this pic variable.. as of now when I do a document.write it always gives me 0, as if it's not assigned inside the if statement

Comment: @user721937 I know that you've found stackoverflow interesting because you've asked several questions in the last 24hrs. Welcome to SO! It's important to us that you review all your questions and accept the answers that solved them. Thank you.

Comment: willdo karlphillip don't worry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is that the pic inside my if statement has a different scope

No, it isn't. JavaScript scope is by function. `var pic = 0;` scopes `pic` to the anonymous function passed to `ready()`. The anonymous function passed to `getLoginStatus()` doesn't use `var` at all, so the scope of `pic` there is the same.

(Since you didn't say what outcome you got or what outcome you were expecting, it is hard to say what the solution to your problem actually is)

Comment: I will be using the pic variable inside the body of my html..so how do I get this? as of now I always get pic as 0, while what I want pic to have some value assigned in the if statement

Comment: The variable is scoped the the function you pass to ready and isn't available outside it. You could get around that using a global (which is ugly) but you would still have a timing issue. You send off a request to Facebook for some data, but it hasn't been processed before the code you put in the body (which you should have discussed in the original question) runs. You need to do **all** logic (that depends on the Facebook data) the in the callback function you pass to `getLoginStatus()`

Answer (score 1):

But there is only one `pic` in that snippet. So the issue you describe doesn't exist. What problem are you experiencing? How does the code misbehave compared with what you expect?

**Update**

Okay, your actual problem is that you're expecting `pic` to be updated so you can use the value of it elsewhere. But consider:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { ... });
```

The reason that function executes a callback, instead of returning `response` as a return value, is because it is asynchronous. It make take a while to get the response, and so it doesn't execute the callback immediately. So your other piece of code is probably executing before that happens, i.e. before `pic` has been properly initialised with a value.

Comment: @user721937 - no, never. The point of the callback is to provide a location to take actions that depend on the result of the previous call - just put the code that needs `pic` in the callback.